# No library specified, yet printf gets linked into C++ program?

Tags: visual-c++, runtime, stdio

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Using MSVC++ 10.0 on Windows 7 x86, I compile it on the command line as follows:

```
cl.exe simple.cpp
```

This produces simple.exe (the compiler automatically calls the linker) and the executable displays the "hello world" message as expected.  When I look into the executable w/ depends.exe, it shows kernel32.dll as the only dependency.  When I dumpbin the contents of kernel32.dll library, there is no printf shown.

Does VC++ employ some sort of optimization so that printf is somehow included directly into the final executable?  If so, how, and is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libc.lib` is no longer used.

The options for static or dynamic inclusion of C runtime library (CRT) on VC++ 10 are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  You can select the one you need/desire in Project Options.

Comment: Thank you for the URL, was not able to find it on my own in the MSDN maze.

Answer (score 3):

MS VC embeds the name of a "default" library into most object files. That library (or those libraries) will be linked unless you specify otherwise with the linker's `-nodefaultlib` option. If you use that by itself, it doesn't link *any* default libraries. Alternatively, you can specify a particular library, something like `-nodefaultlib:mylib.lib`, in which case it links all the default libraries *except* those you specify here.

To use your example, if you use:

```
cl simple.c
```

It'll compile and link correctly. If, however, you use:

```
cl simple.c -link -nodefaultlib
```

You'll get:

> simple.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol printf referenced in function main
>   LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mainCRTStartup
>   simple.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Just to be complete, you can also use the compiler's `/Zl` switch to create the object without embedding the name of any library. This is intended (primarily) for creating static libraries, so they won't embed the name of a library that could conflict with however you build code that uses your library.

Comment: I tried -nodefaultlib and got the exact same output as you have shown.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

printf (actually fprintf to stdout), as well as other "standard" functions malloc, exit etc. are statically linked with libc.lib, that's why you don't see it as a dll anywhere.

Comment: as Steve says below, libc is no longer available, the multithreaded version of it libcmt is now used, but the idea is the same - it is statically built and uses no dlls