# C writing to file from dll, with file opened in application

Tags: c, dll, printf

I have a file pointer exported from a dll, which is initialized(fopen) by the application and then used(fprintf) inside the dll.

The problem is fprintf will throw an exception.

**DLLFile.c**

```
#define BUILD_FOO
#include "API.H"

File *pFile;

void exportedFunction()
{
   fprintf(pFile,"This will result in an exception\n");//<-This print will crash
}
```

**API.H**

```
#ifdef BUILD_FOO
#    define FOOAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define FOOAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

FOOAPI  extern File *pFile;
FOOAPI  void exportedFunction();
```

**APLICATION.C**

```
#undef BUILD_FOO
#include "API.H"
void main()
{
pFile = fopen("path_to_folder","wt");
fprintf(pFile , "This print will work"); // <- This will be printed ok
exportedFunction(); 
}
```

1 From the debugging I've done, this is what I saw:

Inside the **application, fopen()** assigns for **pFile**  an element from **_iob[]**.

In the **DLL** when **fprintf** is called, it is checked that **pFile** is part of the **_iob[]**, but the **_iob[]** from the application seems not to be the same with the one in the DLL(they have different addresses).

2 I have the same  use case(with the same application) and another somewhat similar DLL, and everything works ok there(the _iob[] is at the same place in the application and DLL).

Comment: This answer might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178183/no-library-specified-yet-printf-gets-linked-into-c-program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely being caused by your application and your DLL [disagreeing on which version of the C runtime they're using](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx).  Unless they're both compiled against the **exact** same version of the C runtime, all bets are off, and you can't call CRT functions from one using the data from another or vice-versa.

The safest way to avoid this problem is not to pass `FILE*` pointers across DLL boundaries.  That way, any interaction with a `FILE*` will always happen using the same version of the CRT, and there's no danger of any mismatches.  So your DLL should not expose a `FILE*` variable; instead it should be some opaque type, and all operations on the variable need to happen in the same module.

For example:

```
// API.h
FOOAPI void set_file(void *file);
FOOAPI void set_fprintf_callback(int (*my_fprintf)(void *, const char *, ...));
FOOAPI void exportedFunction();

// DLLFile.c
void *pFile;  // Not exported
int (*fprintf_callback)(void *, const char *, ...);  // Not exported

FOOAPI set_file(void *file)
{
    pFile = file;
}

FOOAPI set_fprintf_callback(int (*my_fprintf)(void *, const char *, ...))
{
    fprintf_callback = my_fprintf;
}

FOOAPI exportedFunction()
{
    // Call back into the application to do the actual fprintf
    fprintf_callback(pFile, "This should not crash");
}

// Application.c
int mydll_fprintf(void *pFile, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    int result = vfprintf((FILE *)pFile, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *pFile = fopen(...);
    set_file(pFile);
    set_fprintf_callback(&mydll_fprintf);
    exportedFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the application pass to the DLL a callback, and in that callback, have the application write to the file.